# Result returning undefined in end result but returns result in axios request

Tags: node.js, axios

```js
var result = [];
const axios = require("axios");
let XBL = 'LINKREADACTED';

function Status() {
    axios.get(XBL).then(res => {
        result.push({
            core: res.data.CoreServices[0],
            payment: res.data.CoreServices[1],
            media: res.data.CoreServices[2],
            gaming: res.data.CoreServices[3]
        });
        console.log(result)
    });
    console.log(result)
    //return result;
}
```

anyone understand how inside the `axios` it returns the result
I need but just outside it, it returns `undefined`?

Comment: Are you trying to return `result` from the `Status()` function?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the from the Status() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a timing issue related to asynchronous calls. The outer result call happens before the result inside the `.then` method. You could refactor the code block so the operations happen inside the `.then` callback. Or I would recommend flattening out the code block rather than nesting logic inside a callback using async/await.

```js
async function Status() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(XBL);
    // Happens after receiving response data
    result.push({
         core: data.CoreServices[0],
         payment: data.CoreServices[1],
         media: data.CoreServices[2],
         gaming: data.CoreServices[3]
    });
    console.log(result)
    return result;
}
```

Note that since the `Status()` function is now `async`, it will return a promise that resolves the result (See the "Return Value" section on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) of async-await).

So, wherever you call the `Status()` function, you should either `await` its result or use `then()`, as is the case with all promises.